# When to use mutexes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, gtkmm

I've been playing around with `gtkmm` and multi-threaded GUIs and stumbled into the concept of a *mutex*. From what I've been able to gather, it serves the purpose of locking access to a variable for a single thread in order to avoid concurrency issues. This I understand, seems rather natural, however I still don't get how and when one should use a *mutex*. I've seen several uses where the mutex is only locked to access particular variables (e.g.[like this tutorial](http://www.velvetcache.org/2008/09/30/gtkmmglibmm-thread-example/comment-page-1#comment-31528)). For which type of variables/data should a mutex be used?

PS: Most of the answers I've found on this subject are rather technical, and since I am far from an expert on this I was looking more for a *conceptual* answer.

Comment: Anything that can have at least one concurrent writer/setter with any other operation (another writer/setter or some related reader/getter) needs mutual exclusion locking of some sort. I'm hard pressed to put it simpler than that. The form that locking takes on can vary, but the concept is honestly that simple. Failure to provide that exclusivity degrades to race conditions that can (and assume they will) result in non-definitive behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data that is accessed from more than a single thread, you probably need a mutex. You usually see something like

```
theMutex.lock()
do_something_with_data()
theMutex.unlock()
```

or a better idiom in c++ would be:

```
{
    MutexGuard m(theMutex)
    do_something_with_data()
}
```

where MutexGuard c'tor does the `lock()` and d'tor does the `unlock()`

This general rule has a few exceptions

- if the data you are using can be accessed in an atomic manner, you don't need a lock. In Visual Studio you have functions like `InterlockedIncrement()` that do this. gcc has it's own facilities to do this.
- If you are accessing the data to only ever read it and never change it, it's usually safe to do without locking. but if even a single thread does any change to the data, all the other threads need to make sure they don't try to read the data while it is being changed. You can also read about Reader-Writer lock for this kind of situations.

Comment: And what would be the downsides of using a mutex where there is no need for one?

Comment: @joaocandre the downside of course is that it adds some overhead. In most cases however that overhead is negligible.

Comment: Another question though, in your example, as well as with the tutorial in http://www.velvetcache.org/2008/09/30/gtkmmglibmm-thread-example/comment-page-1#comment-31528, I see no information passed to the mutex about the data/variables to be protected. How does it know which resources to lock?

Comment: @joaocandre The mutex doesn't need to know anything about what it protects. The fact that you only access the resource while the mutex is locked is what protects the data. The usage of the mutex allows only a single thread to ever enter the area of code where the data is being manipulated. that's what's protecting the data.

Answer (score 1):

variables that are changed among multiple threads. So data that is not modified (immutable) or data that is not shared does not need

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please reformat your answer? It seems partial to me.